# Python: sorting a list by key returns error: 'string must be integers'

Tags: python

I've been searching to no avail and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to:

- call a url which holds a json-formatted file
- convert the resulting dict to a list (I don't think I need the keys that get inserted)
- order the items in that list by a key ('loved_count')

My code is:

```
url = "http://hypem.com/playlist/tags/dance/json/1/data.js"
output = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
output = output.values() #convert dict to list
output = output.sort(key=itemgetter('loved_count')) #sort list by loved_count
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
output = output.sort(key=itemgetter('loved_count')) #sort list by loved_count
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any thoughts on where I'm messing this up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two questions: 1) What is 'loved_count', and 2) Why are you converting the dict to a list (you are losing all the information in the keys)?

Comment: I'm confused by your third requrement "order the items in that list by a key ('loved_count')".  Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Sure. 'loved_count' stores the number of times an item has been "loved" ("liked") on the hypem site. I'm using a list so that I can order elements... dict is unordered and wouldn't let me first sort then do other things to the list IIRC.

Comment: Based on the answer of @falsetru, you omitted the very valuable piece of information that every element of the list was supposed to be a `dict`.  That would have help clear the confusion of what you were trying to do with the `itemgetter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An item in the list is not a dictionary:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import json
>>> url = "http://hypem.com/playlist/tags/dance/json/1/data.js"
>>> output = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
>>> for x in output.values():
...     print(type(x))
... 
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'dict'>
....

>>> u'1.1'['loved_count']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

---

You can workaround by filtering out non-dictionary item(s):

```
>>> items = [x for x in output.values() if isinstance(x, dict)]
>>> items.sort(key=itemgetter('loved_count'))
# No error.
```

But, I'd rather ask the data provider what's wrong with the data because array/list is supported to contain heterogeneous data.

---

BTW, the code is assigning the return value of `sort`. `sort` return `None`; You lose the list. Remove assignment, just call `sort`.

Comment: Or use `sorted` instead of sort - for situations where you do want to have a (shallow) copy